# How to call a URL in Windows Installer?

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I need to check if a URL sends a response before I continue with the installation. I've been searching but I can't find anything on how to go about executing some code in installation projects. Any help to get me heading in the right direction would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Does it need to just send any response, or are you expecting a  particular response?

Comment: 200 would be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is called a [custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368066.aspx). There are various options for packaging custom actions — dll and exe being the most portable. In your case, I'd recommend a managed exe custom action which receives the URL to check and any additional parameters on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

What if the user doesn't have an internet connection?  What if the installation is being done by a tool such as SCCM in the System context with no proxy rights?  What if the user has privacy concerns about the installer phoning home each time?

Does this really belong in the install or can you handle this in the application?  This can only serve to decrease the robustness of your install.

Comment: The user has to have an internet connection to use the program otherwise its worthless. This is for a specific business not for just any end user to use.